# Extraer limite de caracteres de un array (PHP)

Tags: php

Me gustaría extraer los primeros 20 caracteres de ***descripcion*** pero no logro obtener el dato, ¿Qué me aconsejarían?.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
        
            $registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"select id_producto, precio,cantidad ,substr(descripcion,0,20)AS descripcion , nombre from productos where id_categoria='$_GET[id_categoria]' and $fila2[id_producto] =id_producto   ");
    
    $fila4=mysqli_fetch_array($registros2);
    
?>

           echo $fila4['descripcion'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

```php
$first20 = substr($fila4["descripcion"], 0, 20);
```

El primer parámetro recibe el string, el segundo es desde dónde vamos a iniciar a contar, el tercero simboliza hasta donde vamos a contar

---

**Ejemplo**

Vamos a obtener las primera 20 letras de un stirng:

```php
echo substr("Hello world this string has 20 characters, well perhaps not, but PHP is funny",0, 20);
```

Resultado

```
Hello world this str
```

Comment: Hola , gracias por la sugerencia apliqué lo comentado directo cuando imprimo el array pero no se mostró nada                                                                               <?php
      
     
           echo substr($fila4["descripcion"], 0, 20);

    ?>

Comment: @Morgan Qué sale si pones `var_export($fila4["descripcion"]);`?

Comment: Me daba Null , ya lo corregí , y aplicando substr como me comentaste , quedó lo que buscaba , te lo agradezco ;)

Answer (score 0):

En tu código se aprecia que quieres hacerlo a nivel de SQL, pero no funciona porque no estás usando bien la función `substr`:

```
$registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"select ... substr(descripcion,0,20) AS descripcion ...
```

Si, como dices, quieres extraer los primero 20 caracteres, **tienes que indicarle a  `substr`  que empiece a partir del caracter `1`**, como bien explica [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr).

Así debería funcionar:

```
$registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"select ... substr(descripcion,1,20) AS descripcion ...
```

O, una forma más intuitiva y elegante de hacerlo sería con [la función `LEFT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) que no te lía tanto como SUBSTR.

La sintaxis de `LEFT` es más clara:

```
LEFT(str,len)
```

> Devuelve los caracteres `len` más a la izquierda de la cadena `str`, o
> `NULL` si algún argumento es `NULL`.

Aplicándolo a tu código sería:

```
$registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"select ... LEFT(descripcion,20) AS descripcion ...
```